# Plot surface between points in 3d space

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a solid surface with Matplotlib between a set of points. Each surface that I want to plot are between 4 points in the 3D-space, and the points are located on the same plane (although their coordinates might be a bit truncated, pushing the point a bit off the plane). Looking from "above", the 4 points could look like this:

[image: Example of 4 points seen from "above"]

Note that the 4 points don't form a perfect rectangle.
**How do I plot a surface between these 4 points in Matplotlib?** Each point is represented as `[x, y, z]`. I know about the `plot_surface` function but am uncertain about how to use it to plot the surface in a polygon that's not a perfect non rotated rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `ax.plot_trisurf` to construct the surface from triangles:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d as Axes3D

X = np.array([-4.3, -3, 1.2, 1.1])
Y = np.array([-2.3, 2, -4.5, 0.8])
Z = np.array([1., 1., 1., 1.])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
surf1 = ax.plot_trisurf(X, Y, Z, antialiased=True)

plt.show()
```

The output:

[image]

If you want to also remove the line dividing the triangles, pass the same `color` and `edgecolor` to `plot_trisurf`.

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising. I'm running into an issue, however. Do you have any suggestion on how to solve this? The following code produces the error `ValueError: x and y arrays must consist of at least 3 unique points`:

    X = [-0.98424006, -0.35771427, -0.98424006, -0.35771427]
    Y = [-1.0222235, -1.0222235, -0.4215349, -0.4215349]
    Z = [-1.3747598, -1.3747598, -1.3747598, -1.3747598]

    ax.plot_trisurf(X, Y, Z, antialiased=True)

Comment: @AntonGildebrand I am unable to reproduce that behavior as these coordinates work for me.

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong values. The right ones:

X = [-0.98424006, -0.35771427, -0.35771427, -0.98424006]
Y = [-1.3747598, -1.3747598, -1.3747598, -1.3747598]
Z = [-1.0222235, -1.0222235, -0.4215349, -0.4215349]

Comment: @AntonGildebrand It's exactly as the error says: You need 3 points to draw a triangle. If you have only 2 (because 2 of the 4 you have provided are identical), the program can't draw lines. If you're not doing this out of a mistake and want to circumvent this message, simply change the 6th decimal of identical X/Y pairs, so that the pairs have a difference that is slightly larger than 0. (e.g. -0.9842405 and -0.98424006 works).

Comment: that's of course a solution, even though a bit of an ugly solution. What's weird is that switching the order of the Y/Z coordinate vectors makes it work (but of course make the plane look wrong)